# HTTP and HTTPS redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to configure my Apache Server to redirect both:
 Non-SSL `http://support.nile.sd` and SSL `https://support.nile.sd` to the link `https://support.nile.sd/otrs/customer.pl`, HTTP requests are well redirected via this `force-redirect.conf`:

```
    $ vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/force-redirect.conf
       <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName support.nile.sd
        Redirect permanent / https://support.nile.sd/otrs/customer.pl
       </VirtualHost>
```

But HTTPS aren't redirected!! it goes to a strange page as follows:

> Index of /
>
> Name Last modified Size Description

Could you please tell me how to redirect HTTPS also, without having the "Too many redirects ERROR"

Comment: Where is your :443 virtualhost entry? the port :80 virtual entry will only respond to http:// not https://

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it works, I used the *RedirectMatch* expression, on both HTTP and HTTPS Virtual hosts as follows in the same `force-redirect.conf` file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName support.nile.sd
 RedirectMatch permanent (.*)/$ https://support.nile.sd/otrs/customer.pl
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName support.nile.sd
 RedirectMatch permanent (.*)/$ https://support.nile.sd/otrs/customer.pl
 SSLEngine On
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/support.nile.sd/certificate.pem
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/support.nile.sd/privatekey.pem
 SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/support.nile.sd/chainofgod.pem   
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have a rule for port 80, which is regular http:// protocol

I don't see a rule for port 443, which is https

you need to add the following

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName support.nile.sd
 DocumentRoot /var/www/site
 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www_yoursite_com.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt

 Redirect permanent / https://support.nile.sd/otrs/customer.pl
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Using `Redirect` here will result in a _redirect loop_. You'll need to use `RedirectMatch` to redirect from/to a specific URL.

Comment: yes it resulted in a redirection-loop, it didn't work. But it worked with RedirectMatch as i answered. Thanks for the help :)